# VS-Code won't starte because of missing /dev/fd/3

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vs-code installed via snap on openSUSE Leap 15.2
Until rebooting my machine today everything was fine.
Now, when I try to start it, I get the following  error:

```
No protocol specified
[7065:1118/173715.565235:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1473)] Unable to open X display.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
/dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
Server response:
```

I tried rebooting, reinstalling it, and deleting the ~/.config/Code folder, with no success.
Currently I have version 1.51.1 installed.

Edit:
I'm not root and I'm locally on a machine with GUI (KDE). Trying to start code as root gives the same error. Other graphical applications are working fine (like the browser I'm writing this from)

Comment: ["/dev/fd/3"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74454/somethings-special-about-dev-fd-3) is a just "special file".  The *REAL* problem is you're unable to open the GUI. All three errors ("No protocol specified", "Unable to open X display" and "/dev/fd/3: No such file") are all saying the same thing.  Q: Are you starting vscode from a graphical desktop? Q: Are you running as "root"?  Look here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the environment variable called `DISPLAY`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
```

This worked for me